# mysql - join first and last records by group type?

Tags: mysql, indexing

With a table like:

```
idx type dat
0   a    foo1
1   b    foo2
2   c    foo3
3   a    foo4
4   b    foo5
5   c    foo6
6   a    foo7
7   b    foo8
8   c    foo9
```

How can i get the first and last data of each type:

for example:

```
a foo1 foo7
b foo2 foo8
c foo3 foo9
```

I have tried this query, but its way to slow, even with indexes on idx and type:

```
select mins.type, mins.dat, mytable.dat from mytable

--get the maximums
inner join
 (select max(idx) as maxidx from mytable group by type) as a
on a.maxidx = mytable.idx


--join the maximums to the minimums
inner join

--get the minimums
 (select * from mytable inner join (select min(idx) as minidx from mytable group by type) as b 
on b.minidx = mytable.idx ) as mins

on issues.type = mins.type
```

The join of on issues.type = mins.type seems to be what is slowing it down so much because mins.type is derived and not indexed?

Comment: i would write a function to with 2 params, type and order. With type you pass 'a','b','c' and with order i.e 0 to get first, 1 to get last. Finally, a select using that function should be faster than those inner. IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's "funky" functionality of a `GROUP BY` *without* aggregating the other columns, which simply returns the *first* row of the group. The problem then becomes getting the rows into the correct order *before* using this functionality, typically by using an aliased query.

This approach avoids any correlated subqueries (queries per row) and needs just two passes over the table (one for each direction of ordering):

```
select x2.type, x2.dat as first_dat, y2.dat as last_dat
from (select *
  from (select type, dat
    from so8735514
    order by 1, 2) x1
  group by 1) x2
join (select *
  from (select type, dat
    from so8735514
    order by 1, 2 desc) y1
  group by 1) y2 on y2.type = x2.type;
```

Test code:

```
create table so8735514 (idx int, type text, dat text);
insert into so8735514 values
(0, 'a', 'foo1'),
(1, 'b', 'foo2'),
(2, 'c', 'foo3'),
(3, 'a', 'foo4'),
(4, 'b', 'foo5'),
(5, 'c', 'foo6'),
(6, 'a', 'foo7'),
(7, 'b', 'foo8'),
(8, 'c', 'foo9');
```

Output:

```
+------+-----------+----------+
| type | first_dat | last_dat |
+------+-----------+----------+
| a    | foo1      | foo7     |
| b    | foo2      | foo8     |
| c    | foo3      | foo9     |
+------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: I am confused about the order by 1 , 2 desc Shouldn't it be: 1 desc, 2?

Comment: @Myforwik No what I have is correct (ie order `desc` on column 2), because you want to order the *dat* column such that the first record encountered for each type is the *largest*