# Show first and last mysql record in group with other attributes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I would like to ask for help to display some information regarding queries made in a database. I have a table called `membervalues`. In this table, I have 4 fields => (id, memberid, submit_datetime, value). I want to show maximum and minimum `value` of each member based on record `id`. For example, I have following

```
  id | memberid |    submit_datetime    | value
 ------------------------------------------------
  1  |    1     |  2018-01-18 09:44:00  |   86
  2  |    2     |  2018-01-18 10:32:00  |   95
  3  |    3     |  2018-01-18 11:19:00  |   74
  4  |    1     |  2018-01-18 17:57:00  |   84
  5  |    3     |  2018-01-18 18:31:00  |   96
  7  |    1     |  2018-01-19 06:31:00  |   86
  8  |    2     |  2018-01-19 07:31:00  |   94
  9  |    1     |  2018-01-19 08:31:00  |   87
```

What one query will return the following result in php loop?

```
  memberid  |  min_record_value | max_record_value
 ------------------------------------------------
  1         |        86         |       87
  2         |        95         |       94
  3         |        74         |       96
```

I can get the min and max id but through min(id) and max(id) with GROUP BY memberid, but I am not able to figure how to get record value with it as I required above. While searching I came across [mysql - join first and last records by group type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735514/mysql-join-first-and-last-records-by-group-type) and tried to opt for similar approach with

```
select x2.memberid, x2.value as min_record_value, y2.value as max_record_value
from (select *
  from (select memberid, value
    from membervalues
    order by 1, 2) x1
  group by 1) x2
join (select *
  from (select memberid, value
    from membervalues
    order by 1, 2 desc) y1
  group by 1) y2 on y2.memberid = x2.memberid
```

but it returns only first rows value for both as below.

```
  memberid  |  min_record_value | max_record_value
 ------------------------------------------------
  1         |        86         |       86
  2         |        95         |       95
  3         |        74         |       74
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry I have edited question with my tried query. Is that what you meant by posting that link?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Add the tag to the question please.

Comment: @stickybit its 10.4.17 but since I had no idea about the query, so I tried with what I found. Probably query was for old version. Kindly help me according to my version. Thanks

Comment: 10.4.17 isn't a MySQL version number. Presumably it's MariaDB? I edited the tags for you. I also removed the unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to assign a number, starting from `1`, to each record for each `memberid` depending on the position of the record when ordered by `submit_datetime` and `id` (to resolve possible ties). Once in ascending order for the minimum and once in descending order for the maximum. Then you can join the derived table on common `memeberid` and that number and filter for that number being `1`.

```
SELECT xmi.memberid,
       xmi.value min_record_value,
       xma.value max_record_value
       FROM (SELECT v1.memberid,
                    v1.value,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY v1.memberid
                                       ORDER BY v1.submit_datetime ASC,
                                                v1.id ASC) rn
                    FROM membervalues v1) xmi
            INNER JOIN (SELECT v2.memberid,
                               v2.value,
                               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY v2.memberid
                                                  ORDER BY v2.submit_datetime DESC,
                                                           v2.id DESC) rn
                               FROM membervalues v2) xma
                       ON xma.memberid = xmi.memberid
                          AND xma.rn = xmi.rn
       WHERE xma.rn = 1
             AND xmi.rn = 1;
```